# ssh tunneling with GNU parallel

Tags: ssh, gnu-parallel

I would to distribute my script over a series of Virtual Machine that is behind a gate server (gate). The system can be resumed

|_my_client_| ------(gnu parallel --sshlogin)----> |gate| --(ssh)--> |VM_1| / |VM_2|

Basically, to reach the VMs before I have to connect to the gate server.

Is it possible to set up GNU parallel to work in this way?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to set ssh up:

In .ssh/config:

```
Host vm1 vm2
  ProxyCommand ssh gate nc -w 1 %h 22
```

This way you can simply use vm1 and vm2 directly,

Comment: Thank @Ole Tange. Fastastic as usual!